# WLink vs WAnchor / When to use which one

Tags: wt

I'm a bit confused: Don't have WLink and WAnchor the same purpose? Is it just that WLink won't emit the internal Path Changed signal?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Wt::WLink`](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WLink.html) represents a [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator).

It's the *location* of a resource.  It's *information*.

[`Wt::WAnchor`](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WAnchor.html) represents **something you can click on** in a web page.

It's something visual - such as text or an image, **combined with** a `WLink` that is navigated to if you click on the `WAnchor`.